# Linux USB Ethernet connection to Android devices

Tags: android, usb-device

I am attempting to get a USB Ethernet connection between a Linux Device and an Android Tablet, using CDC_ECM/EEM/NCM (or similar), and I am unable to get the Android tablet to detect the Ethernet device in the settings page.

I have found the [following article](https://jordemort.dev/blog/why-android-cant-use-cdc-ethernet/) discussing why Android is unable to detect the USB Ethernet device, and have verified using adb, that the same situation is occurring on my device. a `usb0` network is detected and added to the system, but Android settings is not showing any valid Ethernet connections.

[image: Output of ifconfig on Android Tablet]

Is there any way I can get a USB Eth connection between my two devices, without changing hardware, or changing the Android OS?

Is there a way to software simulate existing driver chips, such as a Realtek, so that Android detects is as that and uses the Realtek driver, and such, enumerates an `eth0` device, instead of a `usb0` device?

Ideally this should work on as many commercial Android devices as possible.